# module display categories and subcategories of my component in joomla

Tags: javascript, php, joomla, module, components

I am developing a Joomla component product catalog that contains two tables:

- products, and
- categories.

I want to make a module that displays categories and subcategories of my product.

When I click on a subcategory I want to display all the products in that subcategory.

How can do I do that?

Comment: Show us your efforts

Comment: @Jeroen thanks for your comment.What i did:in my helper i create a class CategorieHelper where i put my query to select  my categories.next in my view:I display categories in list